# How to convert decimal to IEEE double precision floating point binary in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, verilog

I am trying to generate an MIF file for FPGA synthesis and I am programming in Matlab to do it.

I want numbers ranging from -1 to 1 (-.9,-.8,-.7...1) in IEEE standard double precision floating point so that I can write it onto an MIF file an use in Verilog. Are there any Matlab functions to do this in an easy way? Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
oldFormat = get(0,'Format');
format('hex'); display( -1:0.1:1 );
format(oldFormat);
```

Only the middle line is important.  The other two just put your format back to what it was before ('short' by default).  I don't know for certain that the output conforms to IEEE, but I suspect it will.  According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html#inputarg_Style) this will display a "Hexadecimal representation of a binary double-precision number."

If you want to save them as strings you could print later use sprintf with format `%bx`:

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
for i = 1:length(x)
    vals{i,1} = x(i);
    vals{i,2} = sprintf('%bx',x(i));
    vals{i,3} = dec2bin(hex2dec(sprintf('%bx',x(i))),64);
end
display(vals(:,[1 2]));
display(vals(:,3));
```

Comment: Thanks. This generates 16 bit hex numbers,but would it be possible to multiply a 16 bit hex with 64 bit binary in my multiplier module in verilog? I am a bit new to this.

Comment: As long as your verilog compiler accepts it.  The numbers are stored as bits in the system either way, so all operations in your processor, FPGA, etc., happen in binary.  The only issue is to make sure that your compiler knows you are giving it a double-precision number than an integer, but this will most likely be done in the same way it accepts double-precision binary numbers.

Comment: I added an update that will convert them to binary if you want to do it that way.